# Force <textarea> via JS/jQ to show its full content when clicked (not auto-grow)

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

So i've got a message board (kind of) and people should be able to edit their content on the fly by clicking an "edit-" button.

Up to now i'll get only the full content of the textarea if i type something into it, i could keep alternatively the overflow:auto so i could scroll through the content of the textarea but that would be somehow 1990-ish.

Is there a definitve solution with the help of JS or jQuery for this particular issue?

Haven't found anything related yet here on stackoverflow which covers this particular issue.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please include all relevant code or event better create a snippet that demonstrates the problem you are facing

Comment: Im going to update my question with the code later tonight right after work.